# Is there any way to set inputView for TextField in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to set picker as my inputView for TextField, can I do it with SwiftUI only or I have to use UIKit components with help of framework integration?

Code example in UIKit:

```swift
textField.inputView = UIPickerView()
```

I want to do same, but with SwiftUI's TextField

Comment: It is not clear what problem you have with SwiftUI's `Picker`.

Comment: Not me downvoting, but you really need to add more detail. Do you mean "picker" or `Picker`? Do you have code to point to a specific issue? I know you aren't asking about "framework integration", but could you at least give us details of what you can get working in pure UIKit terms? (Don't be afraid of getting technical or specific, we all have worked with UIKit or AppKit.)

Comment: @Fabian in UIKit i can do something like that: textField.inputView = UIPickerView(), and I want to do same thing with SwiftUI's TextField

Comment: you can try with .background and Picker. A lot of features do not have a direct translation to SwiftUI, but rather need a bit of.   Rebuilding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Xcode 11.4, SwiftUI's `TextField` does not have an equivalent of the `inputView` property of `UITextField`.

You can work around it by bridging a UIKit `UITextField` to SwiftUI, and by bridging a SwiftUI `Picker` to UIKit. You'll need to set the text field's `inputViewController` property rather than its `inputView` property.

#### To bridge a `UITextField` to SwiftUI

Use `UIViewRepresentable` to wrap the `UITextField` in a SwiftUI `View`. Since you create the `UITextField`, you can set its `inputViewController` property to a `UIViewController` that you create.

#### To bridge a SwiftUI `Picker` into UIKit

Use`UIHostingController` to wrap a SwiftUI `Picker` in a `UIViewController`. Set the text field's `inputViewController` to your `UIHostingController` instance.

Comment: UITextField has no inputViewController property. The closest thing I can find is this one, from UIResponder, which the docs say is read-only. Are you aware of some way of setting the inputViewController of a UITextField that I'm not finding?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621117-inputviewcontroller

Comment: Ah, you’re right. You have to subclass `UITextField` and implement the `inputViewController` property in your subclass.

Comment: I did like this but the custome keyboard didn't show, I don't know why, any advice?

Answer (score 7):

The only issue which I found using the above-mentioned solution was that whenever the keyboard gets into the editing phase, then the picker was presented and along with it the keyboard also gets presented.

So there was no way to hide the keyboard and present the picker.
Therefore I have written a custom struct to handle this behaviour similar to what we do using UITextField inputView.
You can use it. This works for my use case.

You can also customise the picker, as well as textfield in the makeUIView methods like I, have done with the background colour of the picker.

```
 struct TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView : UIViewRepresentable {

      var data : [String]
      var placeholder : String

      @Binding var selectionIndex : Int
      @Binding var text : String?

      private let textField = UITextField()
      private let picker = UIPickerView()

      func makeCoordinator() -> TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView.Coordinator {
           Coordinator(textfield: self)
      }

      func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView>) -> UITextField {
           picker.delegate = context.coordinator
           picker.dataSource = context.coordinator
           picker.backgroundColor = .yellow
           picker.tintColor = .black
           textField.placeholder = placeholder
           textField.inputView = picker
           textField.delegate = context.coordinator
           return textField
      }

      func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView>) {
           uiView.text = text
      }

      class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate , UITextFieldDelegate {

           private let parent : TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView

           init(textfield : TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView) {
                self.parent = textfield
           }

           func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
                return 1
           }
           func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
                return self.parent.data.count
           }
           func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
                return self.parent.data[row]
           }
           func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
                self.parent.$selectionIndex.wrappedValue = row
                self.parent.text = self.parent.data[self.parent.selectionIndex]
                self.parent.textField.endEditing(true)

           }
           func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
                self.parent.textField.resignFirstResponder()
           }
     }
 }
```

You can use this as:-

```
 struct ContentView : View {

      @State var gender : String? = nil
      @State var arrGenders = ["Male","Female","Unknown"]
      @State var selectionIndex = 0

      var body : some View {
          VStack {
                   TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView(data: self.arrGenders, placeholder: "select your gender", selectionIndex: self.$selectionIndex, text: self.$gender)
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: It is possible with datepicker?

Comment: @StefanoToppi yes it possible with UIDatePicker also, I have implemented it using the same technique. As I didn't find any question related to it, otherwise I would have answered

Comment: @StefanoToppi you can ask a separate question for the issue, so that I can answer on that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a textfield that can have an input view that is either a picker, a datepicker, or a keyboard:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct CTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    enum PickerType {
        case keyboard(type: UIKeyboardType, autocapitalization: UITextAutocapitalizationType, autocorrection: UITextAutocorrectionType)
        case datePicker(minDate: Date, maxDate: Date)
        case customList(list: [String])
    }
    
    var pickerType: CTextField.PickerType
    
    @Binding var text: String {
        didSet{
            print("text aha: ", text)
        }
    }

    let placeholder: String
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
        textField.frame.size.height = 36
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        textField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        if !self.text.isEmpty{
            textField.text = self.text
        }
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        switch pickerType {
        case .datePicker:
            uiView.text = self.text
        case .customList:
            uiView.text = self.text
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject {
        
        var parent: CTextField
        
        init(_ parent: CTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        private func setPickerType(textField: UITextField) {
            switch parent.pickerType {
            case .keyboard(let type, let autocapitalization, let autocorrection):
                textField.keyboardType = type
                textField.inputView = nil
                textField.autocapitalizationType = autocapitalization
                textField.autocorrectionType = autocorrection
            case .customList(let list):
                textField.inputView = getPicker()
                let row = list.firstIndex(of: parent.text)
                let myPicker = textField.inputView as! UIPickerView
                myPicker.selectRow(row!, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
                
            case .datePicker(let minDate, let maxDate):
                textField.inputView = getDatePicker(minDate: minDate, maxDate: maxDate)
            }
            textField.inputAccessoryView = getToolBar()
        }
        
        
        private func getPicker() -> UIPickerView {
            let picker = UIPickerView()
            picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.dataSource = self
         
            return picker
        }
        
        private func getDatePicker(minDate: Date, maxDate: Date) -> UIDatePicker {
            let picker = UIDatePicker()
            picker.datePickerMode = .date
            picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
            picker.maximumDate = maxDate
            picker.minimumDate = minDate
            picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
            return picker
        }
        
        @objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
            parent.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
        }
        
        
        private func getToolBar() -> UIToolbar {
            let toolBar = UIToolbar()
            toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
            toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
            toolBar.isTranslucent = true
            toolBar.sizeToFit()
            let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.donePicker))
            toolBar.setItems([spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
            toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            return toolBar
        }
        
        @objc func donePicker() {
            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        }
    }
}

extension CTextField.Coordinator: UIPickerViewDataSource{
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        switch parent.pickerType {
         case .customList(let list):
             return list.count
         default:
             return 0
        }
    }
}

extension CTextField.Coordinator: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        switch parent.pickerType {
         case .customList(let list):
           return list[row]
         default:
           return ""
        }
    }

    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        switch parent.pickerType {
         case .customList(let list):
            parent.text = list[row]
            print("parent.text is now: ", parent.text)
         default:
              break
       }
    }
}

extension CTextField.Coordinator: UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        setPickerType(textField: textField)
        return true
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
            defer {
                if let currentText = textField.text, let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) {
                    parent.text = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
                }
            }
        
        return true
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        donePicker()
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a ViewModel like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

let FRIENDS = ["Raquel", "Shekinah", "Sedh", "Sophia"]

class UserSettingsVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = FRIENDS[0]
    @Published var greet = ""
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FriendsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = UserSettingsVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Group {
                    Text(vm.name)
                        .padding()
                    Text(vm.greet)
                        .padding()
                    CTextField(pickerType: .customList(list: FRIENDS), text: $vm.name, placeholder: "Required")
                    CTextField(pickerType: .keyboard(type: .default, autocapitalization: .none, autocorrection: .no
                    ), text: $vm.greet, placeholder: "Required")
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a `TextField` and choose its text using a `Picker` in `SwiftUI`. And you don't want to integrate `UIKit` in `SwiftUI`, the bellow solution may give you some ideas:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var selection = 0
@State private var textfieldValue = ""
@State private var textfieldValue2 = ""
@State private var ispickershowing = false

var values = ["V1", "V2", "V3"]

var body: some View {

    VStack {

        TextField("Pick one from the picker:", text: $textfieldValue, onEditingChanged: {
            edit in

            if edit {
                self.ispickershowing = true
            } else {
                self.ispickershowing = false
            }
        })

        if ispickershowing {

            Picker(selection: $selection, label:
                Text("Pick one:")
                , content: {
                    ForEach(0 ..< values.count) { index in
                        Text(self.values[index])
                            .tag(index)
                    }
            })

            Text("you have picked \(self.values[self.selection])")

            Button(action: {
                self.textfieldValue = self.values[self.selection]
            }, label: {
                Text("Done")
            })
        }

        TextField("simple textField", text: $textfieldValue2)
    }
  }
}
```