# How can I dismiss the keyboard, and have a new view behind it, while keeping the .toolbar visable in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, custom-keyboard

I am looking to be able to click a button, which dismisses the keyboard, and replace the keyboard space with a new view. Notion has this functionality in their app. I've attached a gif for clarity on what functionality I'm trying to achieve.

[image: demo]

Comment: I suspect they're setting [`inputView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618614-inputview) or [`inputViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621117-inputviewcontroller#) on a `UITextView`. SwiftUI doesn't offer an API for this as of iOS 17.4. See if [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57975634/77567) helps you implement a workaround.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what does not work, what errors do you get?  Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [Minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Note to `dismiss` the keyboard use [FocusState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/FocusState), then use that variable to show your specific view once the keyboard is dimissed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the height of the keyboard with

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter
    .default
    .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
    .compactMap { $0.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue }
    .map { $0.cgRectValue.height }, perform: { height in
        self.height = height //Adjust the height based on the keyboard
})
```

Then bring the keyboard in/out by setting

```
@FocusState var isFocused: Bool
```

to `true`/`false`

Here is a full sample.

```
import SwiftUI

struct KeyboardHeightView: View {
    //Use this to bring/dismiss keyboard
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var height: CGFloat = 300
    @State private var text: String = "test"
    @ScaledMetric var buttonHeight = 40
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .focused($isFocused)
            //Parent for buttons and actions
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .border(Color.green)
                .overlay {
                    //Area for buttons and actions
                    VStack {
                        //Space for the buttons
                        HStack{
                            Text("tap to dismiss")
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    isFocused = false //Dismiss Keyboard
                                }
                        }
                        .frame(height: buttonHeight)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .border(Color.red)
                        //Space for other actions.
                        Button("perform some action") {
                            //Do something
                            isFocused = true //Show the  keyboard again.
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: height + buttonHeight) //Keyboard + the space for the buttons that dismiss keyboard and show actions
        }.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter
                .default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
                .compactMap { $0.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue }
                .map { $0.cgRectValue.height }, perform: { height in
                    self.height = height //Adjust the height based on the keyboard
                })
            .task {
                isFocused = true //Show keyboard when the View appears
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    KeyboardHeightView()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. The last thing I added was             `.scrollDismissesKeyboard(.never)`.